# Is there a way to isolate $x$ in $x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{12}=\alpha$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose I have:
> $$
> x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{12}=\alpha
> $$
> for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Is there a way to find $x$?

What I was thinking of is the following process :
$$
x(1+x+\cdots+x^{11})=\alpha\qquad\implies\qquad x+x^{2}+\cdots+x^{10}=\frac{\alpha}{x}-1
$$
So this gives :
$$
x(1+x+\cdots+x^{9})=\frac{\alpha}{x}-1\qquad\implies\qquad x+x^{2}+\cdots+x^{9}=\frac{\frac{\alpha}{x}-1}{x}-1
$$
and so on. Therefore, is there a way to isolate $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using elementary algebra with $x≠1$,

$$\begin{align}x+x^2+x^3+\cdots +x^n&=\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1}=\alpha&\end{align}$$

$$x^{n+1}-x-\alpha x+\alpha=0$$

$$x^{n+1}-x(\alpha+1)+\alpha =0$$

If $n≤4, \alpha \in\mathbb R$, then we always have a explicit solution with finite term of radicals.

If $n≥5, \alpha \in\mathbb R$, then the equation is not solvable with finite term of radicals in general depending on $\alpha.$

This means, for only special $\alpha$ we have explicit solutions.

Comment: Do you have a proof that for $n\geq 5$ there equation is not solvable?  For instance, if $\alpha =12$, I get $x=1$ right away.

Comment: @B.Goddard  But I accepted $x≠1$, in the first line..

Comment: You're missing the point.  Let $\alpha = 8190$ and then $x=2$ is a solution.

Comment: @B.Goddard In general polynomials of degree $\geq 5$ are not solvable using radicals. This is a well-known result of Galois Theory. There might be some cases where this is possible though.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis The question wasn't about general polynomials, but about this particular one.  The poster asserts that this particular one is not solvable.  I'm not convinced.

Comment: @B.Goddard I guess it is possible to calculate (computationally) the Galois group of this polynomial to determine whether or not it is solvable using radicals.

Comment: @B.Goddard I hope I chose the English words right now.

Comment: @B.Goddard This is a well-known fact, for $n≥5$ only general radical solution doesn't exist. For example, $x^5+x-2=0$ is solvable. This is what I wanted to say.  I used missing words. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it matters, but I don't think your new assertion is any better.  We don't know what "special" means here, and I can give uncountably many examples of values for $\alpha$ for which there is a solution.  That doesn't seem very special.  But I have to go to choir practice and I recommend you leave your answer as it is.

Comment: @lonestudent It could be the case that for all values of $a$ this particular polynomial is solvable using radicals. For what it's worth though after a quick check with MAGMA it seems that the Galois group of this polynomial is $S_{13}$ which is not solvable.

Comment: I'm well-aware of the well-known fact.  The problem here is that some 5th-degree and some 12th-degree polynomials ARE solvable.  How do we know this one isn't one of them?

Comment: @B.Goddard I already gave an example to you.(see above comment).By the way Everyone is sleeping where I am now.  Good luck to you.:)

Comment: We don't need an example.  We need a proof that the particular polynomial is not solvable.  @GiorgosGiapitzakis  might have one, but you don't, yet.

Comment: @B.Goddard Well if proof by MAGMA counts then I have one. Otherwise I don't :P

Comment: @lonestudent This question might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253226/why-a-polynomial-is-solvable-by-radicals-iff-its-galois-group-is-solvable-when

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis the word "in general"  this was what I mean.. by impossibility theorem.

Comment: @lonestudent That's not correct. The polynomial $x^{12} - a$ has 12 roots all of which are found using radicals.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis  Proof by MAGMA would at least be something.  The assertion so far is only "Probably not because some high-degree polynomials aren't solvable." Adding the MAGMA data would at least back this up.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.  You have a 12th degree polynomial and so there are 12 solutions for $x$.  If you had a solution it would have to be an unholy mess of several $\pm$'s (or other roots of unity.)

But if you add $1$ to both sides you get"

$$1+x+\cdots+x^{12} = \alpha+1$$

$$\frac{1-x^{13}}{1-x} = \alpha+1.$$

It's not too hard to get the derivative of the left side, and so Newton's method  might give you an approximation to a real root.

Comment: Obviosly, we have inifinitely many **real** solutions.  Take $\alpha=r+r^2+\cdots +r^{12}, r\in\mathbb R$, then $x=r$ is a solution.

Comment: @lonestudent $a$ is a given real number.

Comment: @Giorgos What I mean for degree $12$ we have exact solutions for infinitely many $\alpha\in\mathbb R$

Comment: @lonestudent Yeah that's true but I don't think it's helpful if we want to find all solutions for a given $a$.

Comment: @Giorgos  Sure. What I wanted to say from the very beginning was to say that it is not solvable with radicals in general.

Comment: @lonestudent Looks like that's the case but you haven't proven that fact as of yet.

Comment: @Giorgos I can not do, if even I want. I don't know group theory. I know $x^5-x+1=0$ can not be solved. by radicals ( algebraic, not Bring). But I can not prove it with Galois. But algebraic way is possible. (Abel-Ruffini theorem)